# Selecting multiple child elements of a certain parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was just wondering if CSS can support targeting multiple child elements with some easier syntax.

For example

I only want to change the css for h1, h2, h3 under a div with the id of parent

Normally you have to go...

```
#parent h1, #parent h2, #parent h3 { color:red; }
```

Is there an easier way to do this. Something like...

```
#parent {
  h1,h2,h3 { color:red; }

  .my_class { font-size:100%; } 

  #header { width:100%; }
}
```

In my second hypothetical example, the css will only be applied if the elements are children of #parent.

Thanks

Comment: Why not assign a common class for all them? To me (if I have not misunderstood the question), that is the easiest option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS does not support what you want.

Both [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Less](http://lesscss.org/) do (by chance, exactly as you have written it).

Sass:

> Sass is the most mature, stable, and powerful professional grade CSS extension language in the world.

Less:

> Less is a CSS pre-processor, meaning that it extends the CSS language, adding features that allow variables, mixins, functions and many other techniques that allow you to make CSS that is more maintainable, themable and extendable.

Both products are very mature, share just about every feature the other does, but do have some minor differences between what they extend that make them not 100% compatible with each other (prior to generating CSS).

Answer (score 0):

In css you must use something like this:

```
#parent > h1, #parent > h2, #parent > h3
{
   color: red;
}
```

JSFIDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fg6g7kt6/

Comment: is not easier its way in css .. if you want easier you must use sass or less

Comment: well, the question says "Is there an easier way" .

Comment: My questions asks if there is an easier way to group css rules that only apply to elements found under a specific parent element. My example uses basic css, but what if I wanted to style forms, buttons, p, a tags and other divs but only apply isolated rules under #parent. I know this can be done, but you have to keep repeated #parent in the css form, which is annoying.